# Formula of Expected Shortfall for Generalized extreme value distribution (GEV)

Tags: expected-value, quantiles

i found the formula ofthe ES for GEV here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_shortfall#Generalized_extreme_value_distribution_(GEV)

My problem is that there is no citation, but I need the formula for my thesis.
During my research i didnt find a paper about this topic. Has someone a suggestion, where i can find a citable formula? It would be great if this source explains also the parameters :)

Thanks for your help
Malte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference `[12]` given at the end of that sentence is correct (Khokhlov, "Conditional Value-at-Risk for Uncommon Distributions"). Note that "Conditional Value at Risk" is another name for the Expected Shortfall; propositions E5 and E6 are what you're looking for.